# an issue with my console text editor

Tags: c++, mingw, text-editor

hello I am working on a console text editor in windows 10 using mingw along with a custom include header that gets the x and y position I want and puts the cursor there, however, the backspace is not working correctly, I don't want a reformat of the code, I just want the editor to backspace correctly here is the code that I have:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <xy_functions.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "enter name of file: ";
    string i;
    getline(cin, i);
    ofstream file (i);
    system("cls");
    int linenum = 0;
    int linearea[linenum];
    loop:
        linearea[linenum];
        char ch = _getch();
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 13: linenum += 1; GetXy(0, linenum); file << endl; break; // enter
            case 8: if (linenum > 0)
                    {
                        if (linearea[linenum] == 0)
                        {
                            linenum -= 1;
                            GetXy(0, linenum);
                        }
                    } if (linearea[linenum] > 0)
                    {        linearea[linenum] -= 1;
                            GetXy(linearea[linenum], linenum);
                    } break; // backspace
            case 96: return 0; break;
            default: cout << ch;  file << ch; linearea[linenum] += 1; break;
        }
    goto loop;
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Define "working correctly". Also provide a [mcve]

Comment: `int linearea[linenum];` declares a zero length array since linenum is 0 at that point. Inside your loop `linearea[linenum];` does nothing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja how do I fix that so it retains the line length for each line so backspace works correctly

Comment: Unrelated: Recommend a `while (true)` with nice scope defining braces instead of `loop` and `goto loop;`

Comment: I need to know why backspace isn't working at all when I press it, it does nothing, I want to know how I can make it work without sacrificing other parts of my little editor

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger? Since you haven't provided a complete example, nobody else can.

Comment: I Debugger, No, I use The Mingw Shell, And It Compiles, And I Don't Know How To Provide The Executable

Comment: Compiles simply means the syntax is correct. It doesn't mean that what has been written makes any sense logically. Mingw ships with gdb, a command line debugger. There are many graphical interfaces that can plug into gdb to make things easier for you if you wish.